# How I can get the mobile proxy on Tizen watch web app?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I need to get a mobile proxy for my Tizen app. It's necessary for connection to the server if my watch connect to phone and do not connect to WIFI network. As far as I know, it's possible to do with native app, but I do not know about web app.

Comment: Would you please share some code of native you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

It will print the port to the console after you start your app with wrt-launcher.